# AlamofireImage: how to clear all image cache?

Tags: ios, caching, swift3, uiimage, alamofireimage

How to clear all images from cache using AlamofireImage. I’ve gone through following answers (posted in stack overflow) but none of them working.

[How to clear AlamofireImage setImageWithURL cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33467263/how-to-clear-alamofireimage-setimagewithurl-cache)

[AlamofireImage cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36696288/alamofireimage-cache)

[AlamofireImage how to clean memory and cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39957363/alamofireimage-how-to-clean-memory-and-cache)

Code I’ve tried to clear cache:

```
UIImageView.af_sharedImageDownloader.imageCache?.removeAllImages()
```

I tried this also:

```
let sharedCache = URLCache(memoryCapacity: 0, diskCapacity: 0, diskPath: nil)
URLCache.shared = sharedCache

//Clear all cookies
if let sharedCookies = HTTPCookieStorage.shared.cookies {
      for cookie in sharedCookies {
            HTTPCookieStorage.shared.deleteCookie(cookie)
      }
}


//-----------------------------------
URLCache.shared.removeAllCachedResponses()
```

But it can’t remove all images from cache.

*Note:* I’ve used [AlamofireImage 3.1](https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireImage) to load images.

Comment: you can use this URLCache.shared.removeAllCachedResponses() to remove the cache

Comment: @BhupatBheda I tried this, Testing your suggestion with different scenarios. But it's randomly working. Sometime it requires application restart. Please suggest me more effective solution.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem and part of your solution worked for me:

```
UIImageView.af_sharedImageDownloader.imageCache?.removeAllImages()
UIImageView.af_sharedImageDownloader.sessionManager.session.configuration.urlCache?.removeAllCachedResponses()
```

Let me know if it worked for you too.

In pods, I just put

`pod 'AlamofireImage'`

Comment: swift 5 update:
UIImageView.af.sharedImageDownloader.imageCache?.removeAllImages()
UIImageView.af.sharedImageDownloader.session.sessionConfiguration.urlCache?.removeAllCachedResponses()